# Does the flow velocity increase when diameter is halved? PS: Volumetric flow rate changes

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Let's assume a flow rate $Q_1$ and a pipe of radius $r$ and length $l$, and the velocity through the pipe is $v_{1(large)}$.
We replace half of the pipe length with a pipe of radius $r/2$ and the consider the fluid flows from the larger pipe to the smaller pipe to the outside.
The new flow rate ($Q_2$) drops when you constrict the pipe diameter ($Q_2 < Q_1$).

Using the continuity equation with constant flow $Q_2$, we can say that the velocity in the smaller pipe is 4 times the velocity in the larger pipe. $$ v_{2(small)} = 4 * v_{2(large)} $$

The question is will the new velocity through the smaller diameter pipe be greater than the velocity through the previous pipe diameter?
i.e. is $v_{2(small)} > v_{1(large)}$.
If so, by a factor of what?
Intuitively this makes sense because if I think of a garden hose and constrict it at the outlet the velocity increases than what it was before it was constricted but surely I'm missing something.
Feel free to simplify any assumptions. Let's use water as the fluid and think about a regular plumbing line in a home.

Comment: What is the driving force of the fluid flow? (To be kept constant during the change of pipe geometry.) A given pressure difference between the ends of the pipe?

Comment: I would assume it to be 80 PSI in the first scenario. But I’m not sure if the pressure would remain the same when replacing the pipe with a smaller one.

Comment: No, but that's the point: We need some info about a (not necessarily, but maybe) constant quantity that is driving the flow to be able to determine the flow velocity. If you think of a garden hose, then a given pressure difference would indeed be a good assumption: The pressure at the tap will be a constant given by the pressure from the water mains (or the pipes running through your house or garden) and at the open end we have atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sufficiently small Reynolds number and when boundary effects can be neglected - for a very long pipe, for example - we can use the [Hagen-Poiseuille equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation) for a simple calculation. This states that given viscosity $\mu$, pipe length $L$, volumetric flow rate $Q$ and cross-sectional area $A$ of the pipe there is a pressure drop
$$
\Delta p = \frac{8 \pi \mu L Q}{A^2}
$$
over the length of the pipe.

Now, let's say that the total pressure difference is the same in both geometries. In the second case, with half of the pipe halved in diameter, the total pressure difference will be
$$
\Delta p = \Delta p_{(small)} + \Delta p_{(large)}\,.
$$
It follows (note that the volumetric flow rate is the same - $Q_2$ - in both the narrow and wide part of the tube, simply by continuity)
$$
\Delta p = \frac{8 \pi \mu L Q_1}{A^2} = \frac{8 \pi \mu (L/2) Q_2}{A^2} + \frac{8 \pi \mu (L/2) Q_2}{(A/4)^2}\,,
$$
or after removing what we do not need
$$
Q_1 = Q_2 \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{16}{2}\right) = 8.5 Q_2\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that pressure needs to be held constant.  So
$$
v_{1(large)} A_{1(large)}=8.5v_{2(small)}A_{2(small)}  \\    
A_{1(large)}=A_{2(large)}=4A_{2(small)} \\
v_{1(large)}=2.125 v_{2(small)}  \\
$$
Here $v_{2(small)} < v_{1(large)}$  
If we only replaced $1/1000th$ of the pipe with r/2

$$
Q_1 = Q_2 \left(\frac{999}{1000}+\frac{16}{1000}\right) = 1.015 Q_2 \\

v_{1(large)} = 0.25 v_{2(small)} \\
$$
In this case $v_{2(small)} > v_{1(large)}$  
I'm oversimplifying but makes sense when thinking about garden hose example that constricting pipe increases velocity